# LocalDate into database with JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa

I'm trying to create a table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MENU")
public class Menu {                             
    private LocalDate date; 

    @Column(name = "DATE", nullable = false)
    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }
public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

The create table produces DATE raw(255) not null, and i need it to be date, i read into it and attempted to create a converter:

```
 @Converter(autoApply = true)
    public class LocalDatePersistenceConverter implements
            AttributeConverter<java.time.LocalDate, java.sql.Date> {
        @Override
        public java.sql.Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate entityValue) {
           return java.sql.Date.valueOf(entityValue);
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(java.sql.Date databaseValue) {
            return databaseValue.toLocalDate();
        }
```

But nothing changes, what have i missed?

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: I want the date row to be represented with a date value instead of a raw

Answer (score 0):

Use [`@Column.columnDefinition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition()) to customize the DB type of this column:

```
@Column(name = "DATE", columnDefinition="DATE NOT NULL")
public LocalDate getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: That does not really help me, i'm attempting to use localDate as a date setter, and jpa does not recognize it, so i am forced to use the converter because i still want the DB to mark that field as a DATE field